# MATLAB how to get mouse click coordinates

Tags: matlab, user-interface, axes

I have made my GUI using GUIDE. I have an axes (tag=axes1). An image is displayed in the axes.
When i click on the image(inside axes) I need to get the coordinates.
I get the coordinate values when image is not added to axes.But image is displayed in axes do no obtain the axes. How to get the coordinates?

Answer (score 24):

Let's assume that you've plotted the image with handle `imageHandle` that:

```
imageHandle = imshow(imageObj);
```

You should assign the `ButtonDownFcn` to the image handle not the axes handle that:

```
set(imageHandle,'ButtonDownFcn',@ImageClickCallback);
```

and get the mouse coordinates from this function as follows:

```
function ImageClickCallback ( objectHandle , eventData )
   axesHandle  = get(objectHandle,'Parent');
   coordinates = get(axesHandle,'CurrentPoint'); 
   coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2);
   %// then here you can use coordinates as you want ...
end
```

You can try this small **demo** to check my answer:

```
function demoOnImageClick
clc;clear;
imObj = rand(500,500);
figure;
hAxes = axes();
imageHandle = imshow(imObj);
set(imageHandle,'ButtonDownFcn',@ImageClickCallback);

function ImageClickCallback ( objectHandle , eventData )
axesHandle  = get(objectHandle,'Parent');
coordinates = get(axesHandle,'CurrentPoint'); 
coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2);
message     = sprintf('x: %.1f , y: %.1f',coordinates (1) ,coordinates (2));
helpdlg(message);
end

end
```

Comment: @HelloASP , you can accept the answer if it satisfy your requirements of the question to end the discussion in this question.

Comment: @HelloASP please make sure to check Sameh's answers as correct. thnx :]

Comment: Thanks for the example. Maybe replace `imshow` by `imagesc` since not all Matlab users have the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://mathworks.com/help/images/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the axes handle from the image handle by

```
ah = get( imageHandle, 'Parent' );
```

Then you can get the mouse click position by

```
p = get( ah, 'CurrentPoint' );
```