# MATLAB GUI: how to get mouse click coordinates(need more help on details!)

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am trying to gat the x,y coordinate of the image I loaded in axes by clicking the mouse. I've seen a few answers, such as this one
[MATLAB how to get mouse click coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684577/matlab-how-to-get-mouse-click-coordinates)
My questions is where(under which function?) should I put the

```
imageHandle = imshow(imageObj);
```

as well as

```
set(imageHandle,'ButtonDownFcn',@ImageClickCallback);
```

Sorry for this naive question,
Thanks!

Comment: You would set the `ButtonDownFcn` in `guiName_OpeningFcn`, but with GUIDE, I believe you could just set that with the properties browser and it would be stored in the .fig.  Depending on when `imageObj` is updated, that would go in the appropriate callback or subroutine, possibly in the opening function if the image never changes.

Comment: The frames are mostly updated in the slider bar(tiff sequence), does it mean i should it put it under fucntion slider_callback? Right after the new image is loaded?

Comment: If your slider loads a new image, then that would seem appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success using the "impixel" function as a way to detect x,y coordinates. I would give this a shot:

```
imageHandle = imshow(imageObj);
[clicked_col clicked_row rgb_info] = impixel
```

Note: impixel allows multiple clicks. Press "Enter" to return the x,y info once you're done clicking.

Comment: Thanks ams, I don't think I am there yet. I am currently stuck on the handles of the image and axes...