# Matlab Context Menu and Buttondown function Conflict

Tags: matlab, contextmenu, matlab-guide, axes

I am working on a GUI in Matlab using guide. I want the main axes in the GUI to perform a task on left click of mouse and display context menu with the right click. Can we do it in Matlab?

One idea I thought was to recognize mouse clicks and display context menu using a command. Is there a command in Matlab to do this?

Comment: [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684577/matlab-how-to-get-mouse-click-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the following code in the main axes buttondownfcn callback.

```
if strcmp( get(handles.figure1,'selectionType') , 'normal')
     myfunction();
end

if strcmp( get(handles.figure1,'selectionType') , 'open')
    mainaxes_contextmenu.Visible = 'on';
end
```

Answer (score -1):

All your questions are possible in Matlab. To create context menus programmatically you can read more [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontextmenu.html).

If you are using GUIDE, then you can create the context menus under Tools / Menu Editor / Context Menus as well as the corresponding callback functions.

By the way, you should use [this perfect tool](http://www.google.com) at first, there are tons of examples there!!!